# ObservableCollection instead of Dataset?

Tags: dataset, observablecollection

I was reading in several places of the Internet on the Datasets of Microsoft, where there are many recommendations to use ObservableCollections instead of Datasets, even the datasets are not included in Silverlight (including WP7); however I and can’t find a place that indicates the reason for this recommendation. Can you help me with some explanation or a web reference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with binding UI elements to a `DataSet` is that if the data in the `DataSet` are modified, the UI will not automatically update.

`ObservableCollection` broadcasts the appropriate events so that UI elements can redraw themselves when the data are updated.